# Webflux access log header

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty, access-log

How to customize the reactor access log in Spring webflux?

I am able to turn on reactor netty access log by setting
`-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true`

I would like to customize the format, eg:  I need a few request headers to be logged and remove the IP address.

Any hints to achieve this in Spring Webflux application would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically like this

```
    @Component
public class MyNettyWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer.accessLog(true, x -> AccessLog.create("method={}, uri={}", x.method(), x.uri())));
    }
}
```

More about custom access logging you can find in the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_http_access_log)